# retrieve rectangle from a latitude and longitude coordinates in FME

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, fme-form

I wanted to retrieve a rectangle with FME from two points (point 1: latitude and longitude and point 2: latitude and longitude) that are stored in the postgres database in text fields:
text field 1 = latitude point 1
text field 2 = longitude point 1
text field 3 = latitude point 2
text field 4 = longitude point 2

what transformer used on FME ???

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want a boundingbox? Then read the record, draw the first point with the VertexCreator, add the second point with another VertexCreator and replace the geometry with the BoundingBoxReplacer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it works with 'Vertex Creator' and 'Bounding Box Accumulator' rather than BoundingBoxReplacer, so now I wanted to extract the data that exists only in the rectangle,I use 'spatial filter' but there is no result ???

Comment: I have a hard time to understand what your goal is. You have a table with two coordinates in each row. Then you wanted to draw a rectangle from those two coordinates? What you just did was: 1. create point from first coordinate 2. create line with second coordinate. 3. replace all the features by a single boundingbox. And now you want the lines within the boundingbox as output? I'm lost.

Comment: Yes exactly, I arrived to draw it because of you, now I want from the superposition of the rectangle and data retrieving information containing just in this rectangle

Comment: If I understand, you need to use the FeatureReader transformer. That will read information contained just in a rectangle.